# PHP: object extends an object, how does constructor work?

Tags: php, inheritance, constructor

I have a class User. Then I extend User with some extra information in Profile.

My constructor for Profile looks like this:

```
function __construct($user_id) {
  // This function sets all of User's attributes
  $this->set_user_data($user_id); 

  // This function sets the extra attribute for Profile.
  $this->set_follow_status(); 
}
```

The second function uses `$this->user_id`, an attribute set in the first function. I get this error from the second function: `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context`.

Am I forgetting something about extending objects in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the `set_follow_status` method declared as static? Static methods are executed in the scope of the class, not in the scope of the object, and therefore have no access to any specific instance (`$this` is not set inside of the method).

Comment: Yes it is. Good catch and thanks :) Too fast for me to accept as answer so hang on a bit.